# Eclipse Always Re-Indexes Repository in Android

Tags: java, android, repository

When I'm working in android, at the very bottom-right corner of my Eclipse window, it reads, "Re-indexing repository" whenever I save a file. When this is enabled, Eclipse runs very sluggishly, and it doesn't finish re-indexing unless I forcibly stop it in my Android progress bar. I've gone to my preferences and disabled Git's automatic refresh settings within eclipse with no avail. Any suggestions?